# Raise an exception with traceback starting from caller

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x, traceback

I'm trying to make an automated test framework for a side-project and could use some help creating the assertion checks.

Running this in python...

```
assert(False)
```

Gives you this...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    assert(False)
AssertionError
```

As you can see the traceback lowest level is `assert(False)`. So I made my custom assert that prints when the assert succeeds.

```
def custom_assert(condition):
    if condition:
        print("Yay! It werks!")
    else:
        raise Exception("Nay, it don't werks...")

custom_assert(False)
```

But instead of what `assert` gives, `custom_assert` gives me this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    custom_assert(False)
  File "test.py", line 12, in custom_assert
    raise Exception("Nay, it don't werks...")
Exception: Nay, it don't werks...
```

Which is of course the default behavior. Perfectly useful 99.9999% of the time, but this is that one time it could be improved. It's not useful to know that the method I called to raise an error when the condition is false raised the error.

How can I make my `custom_assert` raise an exception with a traceback starting from the caller, the same way `assert` does?

P.S.: I don't want to print it, I want the exception to have properly modified traceback so it works properly with debuggers and other tools too!

**Edit**

To clarify, the traceback I want would be like this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    custom_assert(False)
Exception: Nay, it don't werks...
```

Comment: Check the[``traceback`` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html), esp. the ``extract_*`` stuff. Might be what you want.

Comment: How is traceback in last example supposed to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what you want to do is something similar to this:

```
tb = None
try:
    raise Exception('foo')
except Exception:
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]

tb.tb_frame = tb.tb_frame.f_back # This line doesn't work
raise Exception('Nay it doesnt werks').with_traceback(tb)
```

but you can't assign tb_frame, and from mucking around in the CPython code, this is C-generated data structures (not python) (see `sys._getframe()`)
So your only option left is to mock the entire machinery and then convince python to use your stack. This looks like what jinja2 is doing. If that's what you choose to do, good luck! (It's out of my scope at that point)